# Power Automate Stored Procedure Empty Resultset

Tags: automation, power-automate, azure-automation

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here with the "Condition" option. No matter what I pass it is always showing up in the "if no" flow.

[image]

Should be in the Yes flow, but appears in No:

[image]

Appears correctly in No

[image]

Comment: Store ResultSets in a string variable before the condition and then post a picture of what the output is please.

Comment: Thanks very much for suggesting that Ethan, as soon as I did that, it made me realise what I needed to do.